# Using TPL to manage hundreds of contexts

Tags: c#, asynchronous-programming, async

Overview of application:

- A chat bot that connects via IRC, using TPL. As messages come from the socket (from `.ReadAsync()`), they are ultimately parsed and passed to a handler within the bot itself (Let's call this `ChatBot`).
- An async long running task responsible for reading certain information from REST API's, and updating various information in various `ChatBot` classes.

My worry:
When the long running thread is writing information, if the ChatBot is currently processing a message, there could be potentially multiple threads accessing the same information. For example: On the long running task, I can potentially read settings from ChatBot, which could also be changed from various commands entered from chat.

I'd like some direction in how to handle this from a TPL standpoint. This is a console app, so I'm trying to figure out how SynchronizationContexts may work, so that each bot runs in it's own context (Multiple threads can process various messages, but only 1 on each bot). Additionally, how to call said `ChatBot` functions from long running task in a thread-safe manner.

Additional Notes:

- This bot is in a few thousand channels. I looked into a few things like `SemaphoreSlim`, but I'm curious how this may scale through the amount of channels, and overhead from locking every single message. (Do I manage a concurrentdictionary with a thousand objects)? I'm also worried about code creep/uglyness, where each long running task needs to acquire a lock for the current bot context.

How would you design this? I appreciate any and all direction.